# slack bot running stops working occassionally

Tags: slack, bots, heroku

I'm following heroku's post [including this specific section](https://blog.heroku.com/how-to-deploy-your-slack-bots-to-heroku#img-src-https-heroku-blog-files-s3-amazonaws-com-posts-1479834037-icon-heroku-png-alt-heroku-configuring-the-bot-on-heroku). If I make a noop change and I'm running a new deploy, the bot responds. But then after some time, I see bot stops responding:

- The heroku dashboard shows nothing weird (does not show it's sleeping)
- The app webpage loads https://yourappname.herokuapp.com (not from cache)
- The logs show no errors

Is it possible this an issue with the starbot code not maintaining an open connection? How can I diagnosis this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a vanilla starbot with no other modifications? Your question is unclear.

Some possible solutions for you, in no particular order:

1) Try running starbot locally and see if it maintains an open connection.

2) Try running starbot on a VPS or some other hosting platform and see if it maintains an open connection.

3) starbot uses [Slack JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack) as the library that handles the underlying Slack connection. It uses quite an old version (6.1.0 according to the [package.json](https://github.com/mattcreager/starbot/blob/master/package.json)). It's possible that this could be the cause. (The current version is 11.0.2.) You could try running a forked version of starbot with updated dependencies, although this might break the code.

4) Building on the previous point, `rtm.client` [looks to not be part of the official API anymore](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.client). On the other hand, I looked at two other random projects on GitHub that implement this library ([retrobot](https://github.com/remy/retrobot) and [accomplish](https://github.com/accomplishes/core)), and both of those seem to use the `rtm.client` syntax, so I'm not able to tell without doing more research on the library. You could try to find a repository on GitHub that contains an already-written bot that uses the most recent version of the library in order to see how it looks/works.

5) You could write your own bot that leverages the Slack JS library directly.

6) You could write your own bot that leverages the [official Slack SDK for NodeJS](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) rather than the unofficial SlackJS.